# unable to incorporate gremlin plugin in neo4j

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, gremlin

I am trying to integrate neo4j with mongodb using gremlin but  uncomment the dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.thinkaurelius.neo4j.plugins=/tp does not work. Neo4j is not getting started

Comment: Maybe you could look into the logs and tell us what kind of errors appears there by updating the question, at least? With version 3.x, this would be in `logs/neo4j.log`(or maybe some additional information in `logs/debug.log`).

Comment: In debug log, I am getting nullpointerException.      2016-07-29 04:44:56.142+0000 WARN  [o.n.b.s.a.BasicAuthentication] Failed authentication attempt for ''
2016-07-29 04:44:56.231+0000 WARN  [o.n.b.s.a.BasicAuthentication] Failed authentication attempt for 'neo4j'
2016-07-29 04:45:02.350+0000 WARN  [o.n.b.s.a.BasicAuthentication] .....In neo4j.log,  2016-07-27 17:54:20.817+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@16ef7583' was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Comment: **Edit the question** and put the **complete** logs from `logs/neo4j.log`, properly formatted if possible. Usually "Component ... was successfully initialized, but failed to start" is followed by an actual stack trace, with the real reason at the bottom.